# Drupal User Permission

Tags: drupal-8

I have created a user with role "typos" and I have a view "mainslider" that slides images.

I have give the anonymous user and the "typos" role  permission to see published content.

- When visit my site as an anonymous user  my mains slider loads with out images.
- When I visit my site as a "typos" user I get an error.
- When I visit my site as an administrator everything is fine

As I said I have given anonymous and "typos" users permission to see published content and my content for the slider main view is published.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you check, if you are using a specific module for the slider, the permissions for this module? Or maybe permissions of files or the folder they are stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that It was not on the slide but on the content type that the slider uses.

I had to set permission for the content type specific content type.

I thought that by setting "view any published content" permission would be enough but it was not.